# to match the case insensitive pattern in if condition

Tags: linux, bash, pattern-matching

There could be below 2 cases in a file: `a.txt`:

case 1:

```
V1=last  #case insensitive
V2=Last  #case insensitive
```

case 2:

```
V1=last     #case insensitive
V2=LastNum  #case insensitive
```

I need to check if both `V1` and `V2` should not be same at any given time.
`V1` and `V2` could be assigned any numbers as well.

I'm using below code , but it's failing in the 2nd case: when `V1=last` and  `V2=LastNum`. The expected output in the case 2 is : `Not Same`.

```
if [[ ( "${V1}" =~ [Ll][Aa][Ss][Tt] && "${V2}" =~ [Ll][Aa][Ss][Tt]$ ) || ( "${V1}" == "${V2}" ) ]];then
  echo "V1 and V2 are same"
else
  echo "Not Same"
fi
```

Any help is most welcome!
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Similar: [bash - case-insensitive matching of variable](//unix.stackexchange.com/q/395685)

Comment: thanks @StéphaneChazelas , the posted answer here by ikkachu works!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you're in Bash, you can use the `${var,,}` expansion to get `$var` turned lowercase:

```
V1=foO V2=Foo
if [[ "${V1,,}" == "${V2,,}" ]]; then
    printf '%s\n' "'$V1' and '$V2' are the same in lowercase";
fi
```

or use `nocasematch`:

```
shopt -s nocasematch
V1=foO V2=Foo
if [[ "$V1" == "$V2" ]]; then
    printf '%s\n' "'$V1' and '$V2' are the same apart from case" ;
fi
```

Though I'm not sure if either of those works well with other than ASCII letters. In general, the issue of uppercase/lowercase comparisons and case-insensitive matching is a bit hairy, and also locale dependent (Turkish [dotted and dotless i](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dotted_and_dotless_I) being the usual example). But if all you have is letters A to Z without diacritics, and an English-compatible locale, or set `LC_ALL=C`, that should work.

---

In Zsh, and with the `extendedglob` option enabled, you could use `(#i)$V2` on the right hand side:

```
setopt extendedglob
V1=foO V2=Foo
if [[ "$V1" == (#i)"$V2" ]]; then
    printf '%s\n' "'$V1' and '$V2' are the same apart from case" ;
fi
```

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas, right, forgot about that one, thanks..

Comment: @User123, failing in what way? If you want to check that `$V1` is contained within `$V2` case insensitively, use `[[ "$V2" = *"$V1"* ]]` with `nocasematch` on

Comment: @User123, note that I had used `v1` and `v2` in lowercase there, while you had `V1` and `V2` in uppercase. That was partly being used to lower-case variable names, and partly `V` and `v` being visually similar. I changed it from the answer now. The case difference makes the variables different, so if you set `V1` and `V2` and test the unset `v1` and `v2`, they'll expand to empty strings, which compare the same.